# How to display form inputs on website

Tags: html, css, forms

I know this may be a broad question and probably difficult to execute, however; I really want to know how to perform it. Lets say I have a form (this a very generic form) as followed:

```
<form>
<fieldset class="inputForm">
<label>
  First Name
  <input type="text" name="First"> <br><br>
</label>
<label>
  Last Name
  <input type="text" name="Last">

</label>
</fieldset>

      <fieldset>
</label>
      <br><br>
    <label>
  Comments
<textarea name="comments"></textarea>
</label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uukuqus8/1/

When the user submits the comment I want the comment to display below the form. In other words, like a blog. I know I can create a container below but how do i connect the container to the inputed data?

Is there any references someone can provide me or examples?

Comment: Do you want to do this without php? Because you didn't add the php tag to your question...

Comment: I have never used php before so I was wondering if it was possible with html and css. I am new to web programming

Comment: @Alyssa Cooke - You will need to use some kind of server side language in order to implement this fully.

Comment: Jup a DB and php (recommended)

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript, however no one would see anyone else's comments since everything would be done on the client side only.

Comment: @j08691 ya what I'm looking for is to make my own site where users can upload their own text document programs. I have the base just wanting to figure out how to store everything.

Comment: It is the easiest to do that with PHP and SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a server-side language: PHP.
You need to make a DB and use SQL to communicate with it.

The form should be submitted with the POST method preferably

```
<form>
```

Change in

```
<form action="page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Use php to handle this input and insert it to the DB using SQL (`INSERT INTO` statement).
Also you will need to apply security checks.

Finally the blog page can get the DB data from the DB using SQL (again) (`SELECT` statement).
And display the data using PHP `echo`

I know it's a lot of work to learn PHP and SQL but I can say without doubt that it is worth to learn it.

You will need to use a database (DB) so check if your hoster provides a database (e.g. MySQL), otherwise install it on your computer (if you are using it as your server)

PHP reference: http://php.net/

Comment: Thanks I will look more into this... do some research and practice. Appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to find a way to submit the data supplied in the form, and save it in a database, and then use PHP to echo all the database entries to print out underneath the form.

You could do this simply by using $_POST variables to write to a database table when the form is submitted, but these days this will get you in trouble with SQL injection.

There are a few tutorials out there in a simple form-to-database - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: So in other words, I would need a database before I can test it?

Comment: Use care when recommending sources from W3schools. http://www.w3fools.com/ Their information is often incorrect or out of date.

Comment: @AlyssaCooke Ideally, yes. You could look at using WAMP (If you're using Windows) to install a local environment of Apache, MySQL and PHP on your computer.

Comment: @Lee Ok thank you. I will look into WAMP server ;)

Comment: @Aly Once you get used to it, it'll be a great, simple way to write data to a database and then print it back on the page.